# How are source-identification and reference-request tags different

Tags: discussion, tag, tag-synonyms

How are [source-identification](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/source-identification) and [reference-request](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/reference-request) tags different?

What are their scopes?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems the following <strike>are</strike> should be informal descriptions for these tags:

- [source-identification](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/source-identification): I heard XYZ is true in Islam; can we identify a source?

  Examples:

  1. [Does the hadith describing "benevolent love towards people" exist?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/q/38209/17163)
  2. [Is this hadith authentic? "Only an honorable man treats women with honor and integrity...."](https://islam.stackexchange.com/q/35374/17163)
  3. [Were pigs made haram because they were going to be extinct?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/q/27903/17163)
- [reference-request](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/reference-request): I want to learn about ABC; how do I go about it?

  Examples:

  1. [Do Muslim sources address the topic of aliens?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/q/14436/17163)
  2. [Where did the -unmarried- daughters of the Prophet (peace be upon him) stay after the death of their mother Khadija (May Allah be pleased with her)?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/q/36307/17163)

However, it looks like [reference-request](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/reference-request) has not been used for this purpose (instead used synonymously with [source-identification](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/source-identification)), and it might be worthwhile remedying this.

---

### Observations

**Tag wiki excerpts**:

[source-identification](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/source-identification) has the [tag wiki excerpt](https://islam.stackexchange.com/help/tag-excerpts):

> Questions seeking either to identify a source or to determine the authenticity of a source. This is not for seeking lists of items that meet a criteria; it is seeking individual known items based on clear descriptions.

The tag [reference-request](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/reference-request) does not have a tag wiki excerpt here (yet), but it's used on other StackExchange sites, e.g.:

> This tag is for questions seeking external references (books, articles, etc.) about a particular subject. Please do not use this as the only tag for a question. -- [reference-request](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/reference-request), math.SE, tag wiki excerpt

This is probably an apt description for this site too.  Other examples: [Academia](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/reference-request), [Christianity](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/reference-request) [Chemistry](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/reference-request), [Cryptography](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/reference-request), [Language Learning](https://languagelearning.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/reference-request).

**Tag network**:

Plotting the tag network (see: [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jfNxt.png); I won't bother giving the full details (the software and instructions are [here](https://github.com/stared/tag-graph-map-of-stackexchange/wiki)), but closer drawn tags are more related to one another), we have:

**Source identification (194 Q's) neighbourhood**:

[image]

[source-identification](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/source-identification) is correlated with [ali](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ali), [authenticity](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/authenticity), [books](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/books), [clarification](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/clarification), [hadith](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/hadith), [history](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/history), [malaikah](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/malaikah), [sunnah-hadith](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sunnah-hadith), [uloom-al-hadith](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/uloom-al-hadith)

**Reference request (40 Q's) neighbourhood**:

[image]

[reference-request](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/reference-request) is strongly correlated with [fiqh](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/fiqh) and not much else.

**Meta tags**:

These are both [meta tags](https://stackoverflow.blog/2010/08/07/the-death-of-meta-tags/) which is discouraged:

> The reason meta-tags are a problem is that they do not describe the content of the question. They describe some other aspect of the question, like the author’s skill level, or the author’s motivation for asking it, or generally what “kind” of question it is (poll, how-to, etc.).

**Other sites**:

- Stats.SE has a "[references](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/references)" tag which [reference-request] was merged into ([meta post](https://stats.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2471/108615)):

  > "References" is our generic tag for questions seeking information about books, papers, presentations, videos of lectures, on-line tutorials, etc., regarding any subject matter that is on-topic for Cross Validated.
- At Physics.SE reference-request is a [synonym](https://physics.stackexchange.com/tags/resource-recommendations/synonyms) of [resource-recommendations](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/resource-recommendations).
- There's a recent proposal at meta.Biology.SE to merge their [reference-request](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/reference-request) tag with their [literature](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/literature) tag: [Tag Synonym Suggestions](https://biology.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3609/tag-synonym-suggestions).

We might also consider merging [reference-request](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/reference-request), [source-identification](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/source-identification), and [authenticity](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/authenticity) into a single [references](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/references) tag (similar to Stats.SE), with the aim of reducing overlapping meta tags (which are discouraged).  The ultimate goal of each of these tags is some reference.  [Just a thought at this stage.]

Comment: Authenticity can prevail as a separate tag.

Comment: It could be helpful to re-edit the tags too.

Answer (score 1):

Shortly speaking it is simple to distinguish between both:

A source-identification means you know about an information, hadith, statement or anything said or recorded by a person and want the source or sources where you may find it. Often here the statement you look for is more or less well described.

Reference-request is you heard about something and you want a proof for its truth or check its truth.